# Calculate condensed distance matrix with varying length data points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Scipy's pdist function expects an evenly shaped numpy array as input.

Working example:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

#Example distance function.
def dfun(u, v):
    return u.sum() + v.sum()

dat0 = np.array([-1, 1,-3, 1])
dat1 = np.array([-1, 1,-3, 1])
dat2 = np.array([ 1, 1, 1, 1])

data = np.array([dat0, dat1, dat2])
distance_matrix = pdist(data, dfun)
squareform(distance_matrix)
```

I got a custom distance function which works with run-length encoded data, thus the arrays may vary in size. When using the following input

```
dat0 = np.array([-1, 1,-4, 1])
dat1 = np.array([-1, 1,-3, 1, 1])
dat2 = np.array([ 1,-6])
```

A value error `ValueError: A 2-dimensional array must be passed.` is raised even though the distance function would be just fine handling the input. Does there exist an alternative to calculate these values?

Edit: the distance function in the above snippet is just an example for a metric which does not care about the actual number of elements inside the datapoint. In my case https://github.com/mclmza/AWarp is used which computes the dtw for sparse data sets example series: `[1,-456,1,1,-23,1]`, thus padding the data is not a valid option.

Comment: Numpy functions works on ND arrays. Sets of variable-sized arrays are not supported.

Comment: What are you referring to as a distance matrix, for you? Can you clarify and elaborate on it?

Comment: I would like to get a condensed distance matrix as returned by pdist which can be used as the input for scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage methods. this condensed distance matrix is a flat ordered list with the pairwise distances calculated between n observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compute the distances using `awarp`, but that distance function takes signals of varying length. So you need to avoid creating an array, because NumPy doesn't allow 'ragged' arrays. Then I think you can do this:

```
from itertools import combinations
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

# Example distance function.
def dfun(u, v):
    return u.sum() + v.sum()

dat0 = np.array([-1, 1,-4, 1])
dat1 = np.array([-1, 1,-3, 1, 1])
dat2 = np.array([ 1,-6])
data = [dat0, dat1, dat2]

dists = [dfun(a, b) for a, b in combinations(data, r=2)]
squareform(dists)
```

For your example, this yields:

```
array([[ 0, -4, -8],
       [-4,  0, -6],
       [-8, -6,  0]])
```

And if `dfun = awarp` then you get this output for those signals:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  2.23606798],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  2.44948974],
       [ 2.23606798,  2.44948974,  0.        ]])
```

I guess this approach only works if `dfun` is commutative, which I think `awarp` is.

Comment: the distance function in my question is just an example. Actually it is using awarp.awarp which can not be padded by inserting zeros without increasing the complexity https://github.com/mclmza/AWarp. I edited the question to refelect this fact

Comment: Okay, I get it now... I updated my answer accordingly. And thanks for mentioning `awarp`, it looks interesting.

Comment: If you are interested I published some slight adjustments to the awarp python version a few minutes ago. https://github.com/KilianB/AWarp  Your answer looks reasonable. I am done for today but will try it out tomorrow and accept your answer if it works. :). Thanks and have a nice weekend.